# Count unique text occurrences in a list in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How can I count the unique names in this column:

name_list= "Nick,John,George,Nick" . I dont have any prior knowledge how long is the list in each row

The answer should be 3 unique names in the name_list

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you can use string_split() function to do so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE ) FROM (
select *  From STRING_SPLIT ('Nick,John,George,Nick', ',') )T
```